# How can I combine onBlur and onFocus in my React Component without reselecting the text on every letter I type in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onblur, onfocus

I have a simple text input that looks like this:

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={listTitle}
    onChange={handleChange}
    autoFocus
    onFocus={handleFocus}
    onBlur={handleFinishEditing}
/>
```

`handleFocus` does just this `e.target.select()`

`onBlur` does just dispatch an action. (and sets the state so it doesn't show the input anymore)

The problem is with the `handleFocus` I think together with `onBlur` it doesn't quite work good together.

Everytime I type in the textfield it is just writing one letter and reselecting that letter.
So it's like on every change the onSelect runs.

When I get rid of the `onFocus` prop everything works as expected (simple react controlled input - where it gets the value from state, and sets the state onChange).

**Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?**

I tried out different `e.preventDefault`on the functions but neither worked. I mean when I'm just typing in something in text field the `onBlur` shouldn't even run. But the onSelect does, but I just want to run this when the component (the input) gets rendered initially.

Here is an example of how it should be: https://codesandbox.io/s/7y66ykqn2q?fontsize=14

This is the repo **Branch: CRUD** : https://github.com/SelfDevTV/trello-clone/tree/CRUD

This is the same code I use on github but to play around with in Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/q3o7zjjjqw

Thx in advance guys!

Comment: "When I get rid of the `onSelect` prop everything" - do you mean "onBlur"?

Comment: Sorry I meant "onFocus", so I I delete the prop `onFocus={handleFocus}` it works (but of course I don't have the auto select anymore)

Comment: Is your component in a collection without a key property?  Maybe it's being destroyed and re-created?

Comment: Good guess but I provide a unique key for every list. I try to create a minimal example on codesandbox to test this out further

Comment: It works on the example https://codesandbox.io/s/7y66ykqn2q?fontsize=14 :\ so it has to be a problem with my code somewhere else. It's a medium sized project (a Trello clone) don't really know where to start debugging :P

Comment: To me it sounds like it's creating a new DOM element. Perhaps use the browser debugger to see if elements get removed / created?

Comment: I would try it on dev tools with right click on the input => break on - node removal, but I can't select it because as soon as I click on it the onBlur fires and it's gone. Any ideas? Here is a gist of that file: https://gist.github.com/SelfDevTV/1886999364bbce0f0f50254d520625f4

Comment: @skyboyer if you are refering to the codesandbox example, the example works as intended. Just my app does not work. The codesandbox example works as I would like it to have.

Comment: you can open Tools by pressing F12, than pause execution with pressing F8 and than change field value(but don't click outside yet). Hopefully you could set up node removal breakpoint this way

Comment: @GeraltDieSocke, yep, already realized I misunderstood you, sorry for that

Comment: You could try something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/3x70o8r711

Comment: Ok thank you. I think it has something to do with the combination of local state + hooks + redux (connected component) will dive deeper into it tomorrow. If I find a solution I will update the post. Thx so far guys

Comment: @AaronHolland your test with JQuery confirms it. It's always deleting the node when I type in a letter. I have to look now why it does it :) But that's one step further. Ty for that great hint

Comment: @GeraltDieSocke Mind if I add an answer to accept?  Good luck with tracking it down.

Comment: btw you may add `componentWillUnmount() { debugger; }` to find out what had initiated that

Comment: Can I see your `handleFocus` function?

Comment: `const handleFocus = e => {

    e.target.select();
  };`

Comment: What I also found out that everything that has to do with typing in text, deletes the node on every letter (also my text area for entering new cards to the trello clone). Here is the repo if you are interested: https://github.com/SelfDevTV/trello-clone 
**Branch: CRUD**

Comment: Ok guys. I might have found the bug, but it's not clear to me yet why it is a bug. When I render the input like this (using styled-components):
`<MyStyledInput propA propB />` the bug is there and it deletes the node everytime.
When I use it like this (don't use styled-components):
`<input propA propB />` it works :D 
So it has something to do with styled-components. I will further investigate :P
I edited my working example with this change, and the error can now be seen very clearly: https://codesandbox.io/s/4w546k8n6x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys I fixed it. **The bug came from `styled-components`**
The bug was related to this part of the docs:

https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#coming-from-css

"Define Styled Components outside of the render method"

At first the component looked like this:

```
const TrelloList = ({ title, cards, listID, index, dispatch }) => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [listTitle, setListTitle] = useState(title);



  const StyledInput = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline-color: blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
`;

  const renderEditInput = () => {
    return (
      <StyledInput
        type="text"
        value={listTitle}
        onChange={handleChange}
        autoFocus
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onBlur={handleFinishEditing}
      />
    );
  };

  // other stuff
```

Now I changed it to look like this:

```
const StyledInput = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline-color: blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
`;

const TrelloList = ({ title, cards, listID, index, dispatch }) => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [listTitle, setListTitle] = useState(title);



  const renderEditInput = () => {
    return (
      <StyledInput
        type="text"
        value={listTitle}
        onChange={handleChange}
        autoFocus
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onBlur={handleFinishEditing}
      />
    );
  };

  // other stuff
```

**This fixes the problem completely and thefore the node doesn't get deleted on every rerender. So this was my fault and I should have read the `styled-components` docs more in depth.**